# redirect using js if window location is 1.html

Tags: javascript, redirect

i am lookingfor js which works like 
if is on a.html then

```
window.location="http://www.a.com/1"
```

else if on page b.html then

```
window.location="http://www.a.com/2"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Where are you stuck? What has your research into finding out what page you're on turned up?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to first check your current location through `window.location.href` to get the url.
Then use `substr(string, begin, lenght (optional) )` to trunc your url to the end

```
//Address of your website
var url="http://example.com/"

function foo(){
    var path=substr(window.location.href,url.length);
    switch(path){
        case "a.html": window.location="http://www.example.com/1"; break;

        case "b.html": window.location="http://www.example.com/2"; break;

    }
}
//don't forget to call your function
```

But this wouldn't work if you have internal likes such as `http://example.com/a.html#about-us` for example

Here is how to handle it

```
//Address of your website
var url="http://example.com/"

function foo(){
    var path=substr(window.location.href,url.length).substring(0, window.location.href.indexOf('#'));
    switch(path){
        case "a.html": window.location="http://www.example.com/1"; break;

        case "b.html": window.location="http://www.example.com/2"; break;

    }
}
//don't forget to call your function
```

For more information

substr()
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp

about Substring
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/substring and